# Globality on manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry

Do the global properties of a differentiable manifold imply the local properties? If $F:M\to N$ is "globally" one-to-one, does it mean that it is locally so? I understand that the inverse is not true; that is if $F$ locally one to one, we could not conclude that $F$ is globally one-to-one.

From another perspective, since I don't understand precisely what a "global" property is, I could say that it is this property that by definition is true whenever the property holds locally, i.e. for any open set in the chart.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function $f:M\to N$ which is one to one, then the restriction $f_{\vert A}$ to any subset $A\subset M$ is one to one, and the pre/post-compostion of $f$ by a bijection is one to one. So, "read in coordinate charts", $f$ is one to one, which means that you can pass from global to local with this property.

Here is a property that is global but not local:

> Being a vector field $v$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$, with isolated zeros, of (global) index 0.

Here the property will be "global". But locally on a suitable neigborhood $U$ of a zero $x$ of $v$, the vector field $v_{\vert U}$ will have for index $ind(v,x)$ which isn't necessarily zero.

I hope this answers your question !